# Partial residual plot based on model average coefficients in R

Tags: r, plot, lm, r-car, mumin

I'm using the R package `MuMIn` to do multimodel inference and the function `model.avg` to average the coefficients estimated by a set of models. To visually compare the data to the estimated relationships based on the averaged coefficients, I want to use partial residual plots, similar to the ones created by the `crPlots` function of the `car` package. I've tried three ways and I'm not sure whether any is appropriate. Here is a demonstration.

```
library(MuMIn)
# Loading the data
data(Cement)
# Creating a full model with all the covariates we are interested in
fullModel <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement, na.action=na.fail)
# Getting all possible models based on the covariates of the full model
muModel <- dredge(fullModel)
# Averaging across all models
avgModel <- model.avg(muModel)
# Getting the averaged coefficients
coefMod <- coef(avgModel)
coefMod
# (Intercept)          X1          X2          X4          X3 
# 65.71487660  1.45607957  0.61085531 -0.49776089 -0.07148454
```

Option 1: Using `crPlots`

```
library(car) # For crPlots
# Creating a duplicate of the fullMode
hackModel <- fullModel
# Changing the coefficents to the averaged coefficients
hackModel$coefficients <- coefMod[names(coef(fullModel))]
# Changing the residuals
hackModel$residuals <- Cement$y - predict(hackModel)
# Plot the hacked model vs the full model
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
crPlots(hackModel, layout=NA)
crPlots(fullModel, layout=NA)
```

Notice that the crPlots of the full and hacked versions with the average coefficients are different.
[image: crPlots Example]

The question here is: Is this appropriate? The results rely on a hack that I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25697144/2870670). Do I need to change parts of the model other than the residuals and the coefficients?

Option 2: Homemade plots

```
# Partial residuals: residuals(hacked model) + beta*x
# X1
# Get partial residuals
prX1 <- resid(hackModel) + coefMod["X1"]*Cement$X1
# Plot the partial residuals
plot(prX1 ~ Cement$X1)
# Add modeled relationship
abline(a=0,b=coefMod["X1"])
# X2 - X4
plot(resid(hackModel) + coefMod["X2"]*X2 ~ X2, data=Cement); abline(a=0,b=coefMod["X2"])
plot(resid(hackModel) + coefMod["X3"]*X3 ~ X3, data=Cement); abline(a=0,b=coefMod["X3"])
plot(resid(hackModel) + coefMod["X4"]*X4 ~ X4, data=Cement); abline(a=0,b=coefMod["X4"])
```

The plot looks different from the ones produced by the `crPlots` above.
[image: home made example]

The partial residuals have similar patterns, but their values and modeled relationships are different. The difference in values appears to due to the fact that crPlots used centered partial residuals (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949964/2870670) for a discussion of partial residuals in R). This brings me to my third option.

Option 3: Homemade plots with centered partial residuals

```
# Get the centered partial residuals
pRes <- resid(hackModel, type='partial')
# X1
# Plot the partial residuals
plot(pRes[,"X1"] ~ Cement$X1)
# Plot the component - modeled relationship
lines(coefMod["X1"]*(X1-mean(X1))~X1, data=Cement)
# X2 - X4
plot(pRes[,"X2"] ~ Cement$X2); lines(coefMod["X2"]*(X2-mean(X2))~X2, data=Cement) 
plot(pRes[,"X3"] ~ Cement$X3); lines(coefMod["X3"]*(X3-mean(X3))~X3, data=Cement)
plot(pRes[,"X4"] ~ Cement$X4); lines(coefMod["X4"]*(X4-mean(X4))~X4, data=Cement)
```

[image: Home made example with centered partial residuals]

Now we have similar values than the `crPlots` above, but the relationships are still different. The difference may be related to the intercepts. But I'm not sure what I should use instead of 0.

Any suggestions of which method is more appropriate? Is there a more straightforward way to get the partial residual plots based on model averaged coefficients?

Many thanks!

Comment: this feels like it might be a [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) question to me ...   I'm not sure why you're neither adding an intercept nor centering the predictor in option #2?  Have you looked inside `car:::crPlot` to see what it's doing? (It looks like it's actually regressing the partial residuals on the relevant variable -- not just using the naive multivariate slope estimate ... I would need to brush up on the theory some more.  Is this spelled out in Fox's *Companion to Applied Regression* ?)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! I don't have access to Fox's book but I've downloaded the source code from `car` and, yes, `crPlot` regresses the partial residuals: `abline(lm(partial.res[,var]~.x), lty=2, lwd=lwd, col=col.lines[1])`. I don't know why this makes sense, but you are right, understanding why would make this question a CrossValidated question. I was hoping for an already made function that plots Component + Residual plots for average model objects from the `MuMIn` package or a confirmation that just changing the residuals and the coefficients in the model would be ok for `crPlot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the `crPlot.lm` source code, it looks like only the functions `residuals(model, type="partial")`, `predict(model, type="terms", term=var)`, and functions associated with finding the names of the variables are used on the model object. It also looks like the relationship is regressed, as @BenBolker suggested. The code used in `crPlot.lm` is: `abline(lm(partial.res[,var]~.x), lty=2, lwd=lwd, col=col.lines[1])`. Thus, I think that changing the coefficients and residuals of the model is sufficient to be able to use `crPlots` on it. I can now also reproduce the results in a homemade way.

```
library(MuMIn)
# Loading the data
data(Cement)
# Creating a full model with all the covariates we are interested in
fullModel <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement, na.action=na.fail)
# Getting all possible models based on the covariates of the full model
muModel <- dredge(fullModel)
# Averaging across all models
avgModel <- model.avg(muModel)
# Getting the averaged coefficients
coefMod <- coef(avgModel)

# Option 1 - crPlots
library(car) # For crPlots
# Creating a duplicate of the fullMode
hackModel <- fullModel
# Changing the coefficents to the averaged coefficient
hackModel$coefficients <- coefMod[names(coef(fullModel))]
# Changing the residuals
hackModel$residuals <- Cement$y - predict(hackModel)

# Plot the crPlots and the regressed homemade version 
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
par(mar=c(3.5,3.5,0.5,0.5), mgp=c(2,1,0))
crPlots(hackModel, layout=NA, ylab="Partial Res", smooth=FALSE)

# Option 4 - Homemade centered and regressed
# Get the centered partial residuals
pRes <- resid(hackModel, type='partial')
# X1 - X4 plot partial residuals and used lm for the relationship
plot(pRes[,"X1"] ~ Cement$X1); abline(lm(pRes[,"X1"]~Cement$X1))
plot(pRes[,"X2"] ~ Cement$X2); abline(lm(pRes[,"X2"]~Cement$X2))
plot(pRes[,"X3"] ~ Cement$X3); abline(lm(pRes[,"X3"]~Cement$X3))
plot(pRes[,"X4"] ~ Cement$X4); abline(lm(pRes[,"X4"]~Cement$X4))
```

[image: comparison of crPlots and regressed]

Comment: I think the lines "Changing the coefficents to the averaged coefficient" should read: hackModel$coefficients <- coefMod[names(coef(avgModel))] and not "coefMod[names(coef(fullModel)" ? Thanks for that great example!

Comment: Any experience performing crPlots on a object of class **glmmadmb** ??

Comment: @Marie Auger-Methe - Any experience creating these plots without the model object? I essentially stored coefficient estimates for a number of model objects in an excel file and don't have the model object anymore. Any suggestions?